# Server Console/Service APP <-> WPF Client communication framework sought

Tags: c#, tcp, websocket, client-server, messaging

I am looking for an open-source framework that can handle communication between my backend host and a WPF frontend client. The following are points I need to consider:

- Client is a WPF desktop app, host is a C# console APP but can also run as Windows Service
- Host can accept connection requests, client connects, but I still seek bi-direction communication capabilities.
- The client and host are not in the same network (need to send messages over the internet)
- Just one (possibly more but less than 10) client will connect to the host.
- I like to be able to handle the following communication patterns: One-way message, two-way request/response, and streaming from host to client.
- The content will consist of serialized POCOs/DTOs and serialized time series data. Each serialized DTO will be of approximately size 400 bytes, the serialized time series can be a lot larger, potentially several megabytes.
- Some messages will be sent scheduled, meaning for example, the host sends a new DTO every second. (if the framework includes such scheduling mechanism then even better)
- I like to be able to stream data to the client, such as a client that receives and then updates data on its GUI in real-time.

My question is: What might be the best C# based framework to handle this? (I run on .Net 4.5) I do not consider WCF because it seems way too thick and complex for what I try to handle. I also do not want to delve into web programming, so Rest/Soap type frameworks are not under consideration. I would be delighted if anyone could recommend a tcp/websocket based framework or similar that is light weight enough to potentially send messages a lot more frequently than just every second.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ZeroMQ for full-duplex communication between WPF client and Server. It is lightweight, very fast and pretty reliable for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are not considering HTTP? It is just over TCP but you don't need to worry about firewalls and stuff, especially given the fact that you want to do this over internet. Self-hosted ASP.NET Web API can be a good candidate. Fire and forget and request/response can be accomplished fairly straight forward and for streaming it has PushStreamContent. ASP.NET Web API is light weight compared to WCF and is open source. Just a suggestion, that's all.

Comment: I played with the idea, in fact I installed the ServiceStack library and run request/response message types. Thing is, I do not need to cater to browser based solutions and thus the overhead that comes along with all the DTO decorations, Requests, Responses, Services far outweighs the the benefit. As long as a framework exists that can handle sockets well then I much prefer using such. I just want to stay far away from http/soap/rest type solutions because both, host and client are desktop apps and that will not change.